# Route after authentication in Ember

Tags: authentication, ember.js

According to the [docs](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/Configuration.html), I should put **routeAfterAuthentication** in my **config/environment.js** file.

My **environment.js** contains the following:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'client',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '',
    locationType: 'auto',
    routeAfterAuthentication: 'dashboard',
...
```

However, it's still not getting redirected to the dashboard route and showing that the **index route is not defined**.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to include ember-simple-auth key like this

```
 var ENV = {
 };
 ...
  ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
    authenticationRoute: 'sign-in',
    routeAfterAuthentication: 'YOUR ROUTE GOES HERE'
  }
...
```

You can also define them by environment inside if (`environment === 'development'`), but for all environments you can put them after var `ENV` declaration. It is also important to import application route mixin so that redirect works (`app / routes / application.js`)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';


export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {});
```